# Connecting mongodb with prisma

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, next.js, prisma

I am new to nextjs and working with prisma for the first time. I am having trouble connecting the prisma to mongo atlas. I did as the documentation said, but whiling pushing to prisma. It is showing me this error.

```
    Error: MongoDB error
    An error occurred during DNS resolution: proto error: io error: A socket operation was attempted to an unreachable network. (os error 10051)
   0: schema_core::commands::schema_push::Calculate `from`
             at schema-engine\core\src\commands\schema_push.rs:43
   1: schema_core::state::SchemaPush
             at schema-engine\core\src\state.rs:433
```

I hope someone knows the solution to it. I have whitelisted all the ip address in the mongo atlas db. This is my db uri mongoddb+srv://<username>:<password>@portfolio.an371af.mongodb.net/portfolio

Hope to hear from someone soon.

Comment: Did you whitelist your IP in MongoDB Atlas?

Comment: Can you check if this solution works?
https://github.com/prisma/prisma/discussions/14908#discussioncomment-6372127